# One setup.exe file including my project and crystalreport Runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have download crystalreport Runtime 13 and i want to included in my setup project. But i dont want to install each of my  files seperately, i want to make one setup.exe which it will include my setup project and CRRuntime,also to installing both of them automatically.

Is it possible?